# ld: library not found for -lGooglePlusUniversal clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, linker, ios7, google-plus

My application uses Login With GooglePlus Feature. It was working perfectly few days back.

I updated my mac to OS Mavericks and now i get this error:

> ld: library not found for -lGooglePlusUniversal
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried adding latest version of google+ sdk for ios but it dint help me.
Why i am getting this?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Have you tried deleting your derived data and restarting xCode?

Comment: Window > Organizer. Select your project from the list. (If you have it open it will say "Open" underneath the project name) Then on the far right, there's a button to delete the Derived Data. Hope that helps. I'd also do a clean. Product > Clean.

Comment: I am still getting the same error after deleting the derived data & cleaning project..

Comment: Ok, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17822349/1126783

Comment: Also, check your project for duplicate .m or .h files, or duplicate classes. I believe this error can also appear when you have duplicate "#imports" too.

Comment: i dnt have duplicate "#imports"